# Create directory in .net standard 1.1

Tags: c#, .net

I have a library that needs to remain on .net standard 1.1, however the system.io.directory api is not available.

How can I create a directory in c# without using Directory.Create()?

Comment: AFAIK, the only options you have are 1) Move to .NET Standard 1.3 or higher and add a reference to [System.IO.FileSystem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem/) 2) Call into the APIs of the OS directly (in which case you will need different code for different OS's).

Comment: Quite typical a challenge, and usually people can use IoC to delegate directory creation to the native platforms. For example, https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-dependency-injection/

Comment: I ended up creating a PCL targeting .net core 1.0 and utilized the PCLStorage nuget package